# To fix mat-fab button in one component

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have created 3 components called.

1. `login`
2. `forgot-pass`
3. `customer`

I have placed all these components in `app.component.html`, one below the other using there respective selector's like this:

```
<app-login></app-login>
<app-forgot-pass></app-forgot-pass>
<app-customer></app-customer>
```

Here I have added a **button**(mat-fab) on the bottom-right of the customer component as shown in below image:

[image]

**Here is issue:** The fab-button should be displayed when we reach customer `component` on scrolling, but it is visible for all of the components meaning the fab-button is overflowing out of the `customer` component as shown in below image:

[image]

I think it's a css issue, I am unable to figure it out.

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/list-examples-bhbw8q?file=app/customer/customer.component.html) link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try to add position `relative` and `absolute`

Here's an example

in `customer.component.html`

```
<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="customer-search">
    <mat-form-field floatLabel=never >
            <input matInput id="search-com" type="text"  placeholder="search"  >
    </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div class="customer-list">
      <mat-selection-list #link>
          <mat-list-option *ngFor="let link of links">
              <a mat-list-item> <span class="customer-names">{{ link }}</span> </a>
          </mat-list-option>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
            {{option}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-selection-list>
        <button mat-fab color="primary" id="add-button" matTooltip="Add customer"><i class="material-icons" >group_add</i></button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

`customer.component.css`

```
.mainDiv{
  position: relative;
}
#add-button{

  right: 20px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: auto;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Here's an updated [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/list-examples-7ypexg?file=app%2Fcustomer%2Fcustomer.component.css)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.